# Which modern JS framework will allow me to use old XML API's?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, ember.js

I have to deal with an old XML style api.

I'd like to use a modern JS framework like Ember, or possibly Angular, even Meteor but I'm not sure what to expect since I have to use XML data and those frameworks are based off of JSON now.

Example request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <OrderXML> 
 <CustomerID>3</CustomerID> 
 <Password>Webgistix</Password> 
 <Order> 
 <ReferenceNumber>ABC123</ReferenceNumber> 
 <Company>Test Company</Company> 
 <Name>Joe Smith</Name> 
 <Address1>123 Main St.</Address1> 
 <Address2></Address2> 
 <Address3></Address3> 
 <City>Olean</City> 
 <State>NY</State> 
 <ZipCode>14760</ZipCode> 
 <Country>United States</Country> 
 <Email>info@webgistix.com</Email> 
 <Phone>1-123-456-7890</Phone> 
 <ShippingInstructions>Ground</ShippingInstructions> 
 <OrderComments>Test Order</OrderComments> 
 <Approve>0</Approve> 
 <Item> 
 <ItemID>example-item-1</ItemID> 
 <ItemQty>1</ItemQty> 
 </Item> 
 </Order>
```

Example response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Completed> 
<Success>True</Success> 
<OrderID>12345</OrderID> 
<BackOrder>False</BackOrder> 
</Completed>
```

---

Any examples of how I could deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) using the parseXML utility.